# Selecting unique fields but am unsure if DISTINCT or GROUP BY will do as I need

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL ver 5.5.8.

Lets say I have the table,entries, structure like so:

```
entry_id int PK
member_id FK
```

there can be multiple entries for each member. I want to get 10 of them at random but I need to fetch them in a way that allows for the odds of being selected increase with the number of entries a member has. I know I could just do something like:

```
SELECT member_id
FROM entries
GROUP BY member_id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

But I'm not sure if that will do what I want. Will MySQL group the records THEN select 10? If that were the case then every member would have the same chance to get picked, which is not what I want. I have done some testing and searching but can't come up with a definitive answer. Does anyone know if this will do what I want or do I have to do things a different way? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT 10` will choose 10 records base in (in this case) a random order. This is indeed after the grouping.

Maybe you can `ORDER BY RAND() / count(*)`. That way, the number is likely to be smaller for users with more questions, thus they are more likely to be in the top 10.

[edit]

By the way, it seems that over time (as the data grows) `ORDER BY RAND()` becomes slower. There are a couple of ways to work around that. Mediawiki (software behind Wikipedia) has an interesting method: It generates a random number for each page, so when you select 'random page', it generates one random number between 0 and 1 and selects the page that is closest to that number:

```
WHERE number > {randomNumber} ORDER BY number LIMIT 1`
```

That saves having to generate that temporary table for each query. You will need to periodically re-generate the numbers if your data grows, and you must make sure the numbers are evenly generated. That is easy enough: For new records, you can just generate a random number. Periodically the entire list is updated: All records are queried. Then, each record in that order is assigned a number between 0 and 1, but in an incrementing number, that increments `1 / recordCount`. That way, the records are evenly spaced, and the change of finding them is the same for each one of them.

You could use that method too. It will make your query faster in the long run, and you could make the distribution smarter: 1) Instead of using 'memberCount', you can use 'totalEntryCount'. 2) Instead of incrementing by `1 / 'memberCount'`, you could use `entryCountForMember / totalEntryCount`. That way, the gap before members with more entries will be bigger, therefor, the chance of them matching the random number will be bigger as well. For instance, your members may look like this:

```
name  entries   number  delta
bob        10     0.1    0.10
john        1     0.11   0.01
jim         5     0.16   0.05
fred       84     1      0.84
```

The delta isn't saved, of course, but it shows the added number. In the Mediawiki example, this delta would be the same for each page, but in your case, it could depend on the number of entries. Now you see, there's only a small gap between bob and john, so the chance that you pick a random number between 0 and bob is ten times as large as picking a random number between bob and john. So, chances of picking bob are ten times as large as picking john.

You will need a (cron) job to periodically redistribute the numbers, because you don't want to do that on each modification, but for the kind of data you're dealing with, it doesn't have to be real-time, and it makes your queries a lot faster if you got many members and many entries.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Forgive me, but I'm not sure how ORDER BY RAND() / COUNT(*) would make the members with less entries be less likely to be picked. Could you explain? Thanks!

Comment: Well, for members with 1 entry, it returns a number between 0 and 1, evenly devided, while for a member with 10 entries, it returns a number between 0 and 0.1. The member with 1 entry will only have a 1 in 10 chance to be in that range, so the member with 10 entries will have a far better chance to be 'on top'. I'm not sure if the odds are exactly 10 times better (because even if member'1' is between 0 and 0.1, it still has to beat member'10', which is always in that range), but it will be close.

Comment: Ofcourse, if you like, you can multiply or divide the result by a chosen factor, to adjust the odds to your liking. After all, maybe you don't want a member with 100 entries to have a 100 times better chance to show up in the results. And you could choose to use functions like `least` or `greatest` to cap the result to a given number, for example `ORDER BY RAND() / GREATEST(count(*), 100) to never divide by a number greater than 100.

Comment: @GolexTrol thanks again for the responses. From what I've read ORDER BY RAND() creates a temporary table and assigns each item a sorting index. Is this sorting index a number between 0 and 1? Are the results that are on "top" the lowest numbers? Is this why your suggested solution would work? Thanks again for the help here.

Comment: I'm not sure about the ins and outs of `ORDER BY RAND()`, but the `RAND` function returns a number between 0 and 1. I can imagine why ORDER BY would use a temporary table, because otherwise, each evaluation of a record during the sorting would cause the record to have a different value and thus a different position in the results. So, I expect that each row gets a single random value, by which it is sorted, but I do believe that my multiplication will influence that number.

Comment: I've added an explanation about an alternative random picking that Mediawiki uses. Maybe you could use it as well. It is an easy, effective, and efficient way to pick a single record, and with the modification I described you can use it to give more 'weight' to members with more entries. It involves using a cron-job, though, and you will have to pick records one by one, so you'll need to query 10 times to get 10 records. May be useful nonethe less, and if not, just ignore it. ;)